# Django celery custom periodic task not executing

Tags: python, django, celery, djcelery

I tried [using this code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/celery-users/CZXCh8sCK5Q/ihZgMV2HWWYJ) to try to dynamically add / remove scheduled tasks.

My tasks.py file looks like this:

```
from celery.decorators import task
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@task
def mytask():
    log.debug("Executing task")
    return
```

The problem is that the tasks do not actually execute (i.e there is no log output), *but* I get the following messages in my celery log file, exactly on schedule:

```
[2013-05-10 04:53:00,005: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker:   cron.tasks.mytask[dfcf397b-e30b-45bd-9f5f-11a17a51b6c4]
[2013-05-10 04:54:00,007: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: cron.tasks.mytask[f013b3cd-6a0f-4060-8bcc-3bb51ffaf092]
[2013-05-10 04:55:00,007: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: cron.tasks.mytask[dfc0d563-ff4b-4132-955a-4293dd3a9ac7]
[2013-05-10 04:56:00,012: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: cron.tasks.mytask[ba093535-0d70-4dc5-89e4-441b72cfb61f]
```

I can definitely confirm that the logger is configured correctly and working fine. If I were to try and call `result = mytask.delay()` in the interactive shell, `result.state` will indefinitely contain the state `PENDING`.

EDIT: See also [Django Celery Periodic Tasks Run But RabbitMQ Queues Aren't Consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275884/django-celery-periodic-tasks-run-but-rabbitmq-queues-arent-consumed?rq=1)

Comment: What result backend do you use?

Comment: @gatto I'm using amqp

Comment: I will try using redis instead to see if it related to the message broker

Comment: I didn't use redis but tried using the django:// message broker and mysql backend just to see, and it works. I also looked into the rabbitmq logs and its a mess with constant abrupt disconnects. I'm working on Windows at the moment (not a good idea at all), and will try RabbitMQ again on a proper OS...

Comment: @gatto thanks for pushing me in the right direction