# RabbitMQ Queued messages keep increasing

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

We have a Windows based Celery/RabbitMQ server that executes long-running python tasks out-of-process for our web application.
What this does, for example, is take a CSV file and process each line. For every line it books one or more records in our database.

This seems to work fine, I can see the records being booked by the worker processes. However, when I check the rabbitMQ server with the management plugin (the web based management tool) I see the Queued messages increasing, and not coming back down.
[image: Queued messages chart]

Under connections I see 116 connections, about 10-15 per virtual host, all "running" but when I click through, most of them have 'idle' as State.
I'm also wondering why these connections are still open, and if there is something I need to change to make them close themselves:
[image]

Under 'Queues' I can see more than 6200 items with state 'idle', and not decreasing.

So concretely I'm asking if these are normal statistics or if I should worry about the Queues increasing but not coming back down and the persistent connections that don't seem to close...

Other than the rather concise help inside the management tool, I can't seem to find any information about what these stats mean and if they are good or bad.

I'd also like to know why the messages are still visible in the queues, and why they are not removed, as the tasks seem t be completed just fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sending an Ack back to acknowledge that the message has been handled?  While the connections might stay around, I'd expect the queued messages to fall.

Comment: Hi @DavinTryon, The tasks are handled by Celery, which allows us to simply decorate a Python function with @@celery.task, I don't know how celery handles acknowledgements internally. However, when I run  rabbitmqctl list_consumers, I get a consumer that has the acknowledgment required boolean set to False.

Comment: @DavinTryon; it seems that Celery's default is to acknowledge a task as soon as the worker picks it up: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question;

Celery sends a result message back for every task in the calling code. This message is sent back via the same AMPQ queue.
This is why the tasks were working, but the queue kept filling up. We were not handling these results, or even interested in them.

I added `ignore_result=True` to the celery task, so the task does *not* send result messages back into the queue. This was the main solution to the problem.

Furthermore, the configuration option CELERY_SEND_EVENTS=False was added to speed up celery. If set to TRUE, this option has Celery send events for external monitoring tools.

On top of that CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600 now makes sure that even if results are sent back, that they expire after one hour if not picked up/acknowledged.

Finally CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT was set to False, this configures celery to not store these result messages on disk. They will vanish when the server crashes, which is fine in our case, as we don't use them.

So in short; if you don't need feedback in your app about if and when the tasks are finished, use `ignore_result=True` on the celery task, so that no messages are sent back.
If you *do* need that information, make sure you pick up and handle the results, so that the queue stops filling up.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the reliability then you can make your queues transient.

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#optimizing-transient-queues

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE = 'transient'
```

Comment: I'm okay with persistent messages, in fact, I'd perfer it over transient, and I'm not really sure how this would solve the problem; the messages seem to stay queued, making them transient would only cause the messages to be lost when there is a calamity.